# Basico sobre Notificações HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, apache

Gostaria de saber como **incluir notificações** em meus sites, o mais básico possível. Pesquisei um pouco sobre isso mas não consegui nenhum resultado ... espero que vocês possam ajudar.

Além dessa duvida... Queria saber se fazer notificações usando o [***Cocoon.io***](https://cocoon.io) se tiverem algum exemplo de como usar notificações nessa ferramenta por favor coloquem ai nas respostas

**OBRIGADO**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil de se usar notificações em aplicações web é usar a API do html5 de notificações de navegador.

É bem simples, o exemplo que vou por aqui vem do [Tableless](http://tableless.com.br/web-notifications-api/)

```
var notify = function() {
  if(!window.Notification) {
    console.log('Este browser não suporta Web Notifications!');
    return;
  }

  if (Notification.permission === 'default') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function() {
      console.log('Usuário não falou se quer ou não notificações. Logo, o requestPermission pede a permissão pra ele.');
    });
  } else if (Notification.permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('Usuário deu permissão');

    var notification = new Notification('O título da Notifcação', {
     body: 'Mensagem do corpo da notificação',
     tag: 'string única que previne notificações duplicadas',
    });
    notification.onshow = function() {
     console.log('onshow: evento quando a notificação é exibida')
    },
    notification.onclick = function() {
     console.log('onclick: evento quando a notificação é clicada')
    },
    notification.onclose = function() {
     console.log('onclose: evento quando a notificação é fechada')
    },
    notification.onerror = function() {
     console.log('onerror: evento quando a notificação não pode ser exibida. É disparado quando a permissão é defualt ou denied')
    }

  } else if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
    console.log('Usuário não deu permissão');
  }

};
```

E também tem uma biblioteca legalzinha pra simular notificações dentro da aplicação, não de browser, [notify.js](https://notifyjs.com).